# Issues parsing version from text using regular expressions

Tags: regex, text, ansible

I am trying to pull the version number out of a text using a regular expression, can't seem to find the right combination.

I have the following strings

- 1.0.0
- 1.0.0.0
- 19.0.18
- 5:19.03.11~3-0~ubuntu-focal
- 9:19.03.11~3-0~ubuntu-focal
- 18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu

I am want to only receive the following

- 1.0.0
- 1.0.0.0
- 19.0.18
- 19.03.11
- 19.03.11
- 18.06.3

I am also doing this in ansible if there is any helpful ansible functions to help with this, currently using regex_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those inputs, a simple regular expression like `(\d+\.){2,3}\d+` will work. If you're extracting these versions for comparison, you might be able to use Ansible's [version_compare](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison) in non-strict mode.